# Traversing nodes but including the starting node in the result in Neo4J with Gremlin

Tags: c#, neo4j, gremlin, neo4jclient

I have a graph representing users and some articles they wrote. I need to create something like an activity stream including the articles wrote by the user and also by its friends.

http://twitpic.com/a342f4

I can have all the user's friends’ posts like this:

```
g.v(4).out("KNOWS").out("POSTED")
```

and returns

```
v[9]
v[11]
```

But I also need to include the posts from the original user retrieved with query:

```
g.v(4).out("POSTED")
```

this returns

```
v[10]
```

How can I have all the posts without having to do 2 queries and then merging them later?
I need to get something like this in return:

```
v[9]
v[10]
v[11]
```

Thanks

PD: I'm using Gremlin and Neo4jClient but if anyone have a better solution with something else its will be fine too, at this point I still can change some of the tools I'm using

Comment: Are you restricted to using gremlin? Is Cypher an option, if so this could be done with a Cypher query.

Comment: Not at all, I'm researching Neo4j for a C# project so basically I can change anything as long as I can implement it on C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Gremlin's aggregate step and Groovy's unique method:

```
posts = []
g.v(4).out('POSTED').aggregate(posts).iterate()
g.v(4).out('KNOWS').out('POSTED').aggregate(posts).iterate()
return posts.unique()
```

See...

- https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Gremlin-Steps
- http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, this should fit his needs perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will try to do it using the C# library and let you know how it when.

Comment: @espeed This does exactly what I need, I just have to figure out how to do it on the .Net client.

Comment: Hi Malave. I could show you how to do it in Bulbs, but I'm not too familiar with the C# library. This would be a good question to ask on the Neo4j mailing list. I know the C# authors hang out there.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a gremlin, but you said you were open to cypher as well, which may represent the query in different format

```
START
    user=node(4)
MATCH
    user-[:POSTED]->posts,
    user-[:KNOWS]->()-[:POSTED]->friendPosts
RETURN
    posts, friendPosts
```

this will return the results you seek using Cypher.

//EDIT Explanation: This will first traverse and grab all the posts by the user, then will traverse across to the friend, which is now anonymous since we don't actually need the friend information, then traverses to the friends posts.